# CSS: adding margin and padding provoke screen jumping

Tags: html, css

If I add `margin` and `padding` for this class, it starts twitching like on second GIF.

If I remove `margin` and `padding` everything is good, but I need them for styling.

What causing this and how can I fix it?

1 GIF

```
.ant-layout.ant-layout-has-sider {
  max-width: 1440px;
}
```

2 GIF

```
.ant-layout.ant-layout-has-sider {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0 0 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything twitching on the first GIF

Comment: `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` may help.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and create a [mcve] including your html - we can't really debug a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to add `hasSider` prop for Antd Layout component